# sed or awk replace from a specific position to a specific position

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have two questions:

1. I want to replace column 10 to 19 in line 35 to 40 with '0123456789'. How can I do that with awk or sed?
2. If I don't know where the line ends, but I want to replace all characters from column position 10 to the end of the line with string '0123456789', how can I achieve that with sed or awk?

Here by saying column, I mean one character per column, not that kind of column in delimited data file.

Comment: The only "silly" method I know how to do it is to make a full line substitution by sed:

sed -i "35s/.*/whatever_comes_before0123456789whatever_comes_after/"

I cannot find a clever way of doing it without throughout reading the REGEX and SED manual.

Comment: Have you tried to google your question subject? **sed or awk replace from a specific position to a specific position**

Comment: Yes, I googled and searched for almost one hour without finding what I am looking for. I thought it should be a simple and common question.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '35,40s/^\(.\{9\}\).\{10\}/\10123456789/' file
```

Replacing everything from column 10 to the end of the line using the same line criteria:

```
sed '35,40s/^\(.\{9\}\).*/\10123456789/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

For (1):

```
awk 'NR >= 35 && NR <= 40 {start = substr($0, 1, 9) ; end = substr($0, 20); print start "0123456789" end}'
```

For (2):

```
awk 'NR >= 35 && NR <= 40 {start = substr($0, 1, 9) ; print start "0123456789"}'
```

In both cases, we're simply taking your '0123456789' string and tacking on the rest of the line.  The only difference is that the second one needs only the start of the line.

Comment: Note that when setting `end`, you can simply use `substr($0,20)` to capture text from position 20 to the end of `$0`. Also, why do you bother with interim variables? Is it just for readability? I'd have shortened the line by loading everything onto the `print`.

Comment: In both cases to make it very clear to the reader.  Yes, it can be made much shorter.

Comment: Well, clarity++, but in the case of the `end` varilable, I believe your solution is a little less clear. The third option to `substr()` is the length of the substring it should return, which if the second option is >0, *must* always be less than the length of the original string. As it stands, you are requesting a smaller portion of the original string, that is the same length as the original string.  Which makes no sense. Awk is flexible enough to give you what you want instead of what you're asking for, but I wouldn't call that very clear.